# want to find a program or other sources that can help me find subliminal recordings in my custom cd's

Tags: audio-recording, software, mixing, daw, editing

I have purchased custom subliminal cd's and I have using them for over 3 months now and I am not sure if the message I wanted on it is even on there or what message is on there and or even if  there is a message period. How can I find the message in the background. I just want to make sure I'm not being ripped off.

Comment: Listen to [Geogaddi](http://www.discogs.com/Boards-Of-Canada-Geogaddi/master/2129). There are plenty in there.

Comment: you mean that there are plenty of messages or plenty of programs to find the messages.

Comment: Plenty of messages. It may be helpful to see how people found the messages in Geogaddi and emulate what they did.

Comment: will do, Thanks from California USA for the responding. I know there has to be away. I was thinking about renting a hour or 2 at a recording studio

Answer (score 4):

Subliminal CDs are pretty much a rip-off. The science is weak, but even if you did want to uncover the "subliminal" message, it'd take a ton of work (think of isolating vocals from a mixed down song). Since some of the methods for encoding the message involve reversing it or placing it outside the human hearing threshold (plausible deniability :D), this complicates things greatly. Get your money back as soon as possible.

Comment: thanks that is what I was thinking but I had to ask. very to the point answer

Answer (score 2):

Find the exact same recording (sans subliminal) and match up the first zero-crossing. Invert one of them. Anything left over is the difference between the two signals. If you have nothing, then there's nothing there. If you have more, then hopefully there's not too much left that makes it impossible for you to distinguish them.

Comment: do I need a program to do the match up and invert 1 against the other. I am a novice but I do figure things out pretty quick. Thanks again for even giving me a idea

Comment: This is the right answer, and Audio Diff Maker is the free tool to do it: http://www.libinst.com/Audio%20DiffMaker.htm

Comment: Thank you for everyones input this has been very very helpful